# Width resize on mobile to fit screen

Tags: html, css

I made a `dropdown` menu for my *navbar*, but the problem is, the `width` of that `div` is `825px`, and it has to be that way to display properly on desktops, but the issue is I can't get it to display properly on mobile. I'm looking for a way for it to automatically reduce the width when on mobile.
Thank you!

```
/*dropdown button the container div needed to position the dropdown content*/
.ddmenu { 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */ 
.ddmenu-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -132px;
    top: 26px;
    background-color: #212125;
    width: 825px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.ddmenu-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; 
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.ddmenu-content a:hover {background-color: #0174DF}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.ddmenu:hover .ddmenu-content { display: block; }

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */ 
.ddmenu:hover .dropbtn { background-color: #0215cb; }
```

Comment: Either write media query or use bootstrap. I'd prefer you to go for bootstrap. You just have to include different classes. For example, for large desktops use class col-lg, for mobile devices use col-xs etc. You can know about it in details here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Its better to post your full code as a **Stack Snippet** in your que for a better look into the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is device specific style sheets:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)' href='mobile.css' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Works flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `width: 825px;` to `width: 100%;` and add `max-width: 825px;`

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */ 
.ddmenu-content { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -132px; 
    top: 26px; 
    background-color: #212125; 
    width: 825px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

In this way you can have maximum width of 825px; which is would be on desktop and when you reduce the size of the screen it will take width as 100%

Comment: That doesn't work, the width of the div adjusts to the content, making it smaller than 825px; on desktop.

Comment: @Oliver I did some changes and made a fiddle for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/yovanverma/vLfqtn4j/

I hope this work for you